# What is the detailed order of how to make a high-to-low-poly 3D game-ready rigged character?

Tags: texturing, workflow, topology

I believe this has probably been answered in bits and pieces, but I was looking for a comprehensive order in which how to model, design & set up animated character from start to finish (coding-ready finished) without any assistance whatsoever in the development pipeline. In other words, do all steps solo before the programmer handles the asset.

These areas include modeling, texturing, and rigging, but I'm not sure what the work order (generally and specifically) should be.

For example, does retopology come before texturing? When do I bake the displacement? Does rigging come before texturing?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if anyone will write a comprehensive guide for you here. There must be plenty tutorials on the web about the pipeline. My 2 cents for your concrete questions: Yes normally retopo comes before texturing because you usually need to have a UV map for texturing which you make from the low poly mesh. Rigging can be done before or after texturing. You can bake the hi poly to low poly as a normal map when you retopoed and uved your low poly. I dont think people use real displacement in games because it is too heavy on the gpu/cpu.